# Помеленный или помоленный?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Правильно говорить "помоленный" или "помеленный"? Допустим, в предложении "На кухне уже есть недавно ... кофе".

Comment: А то, что на пачке написано, не подходит?

Comment: В том и дело, что нет никакой упаковки, а "кофе" идет как пример того, что можно помолоть)

Comment: О кофе, который в пачке, лучше сказать просто "молотый", если он действительно помолот. Но мой Вам совет: не покупайте такой, а мелите и варите в турке сразу!))) Причём молоть надо "в муку", т. е. максимально мелко, и на хорошей турецкой кофемолке для равномерного мелкого помола.

Answer (score 1):

Слова "помоленный" нет в природе; есть бесприставочное "моленный" от слова... "молить" и "моление", [см](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_udarenie/22280/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Кофий у нас будет молотый или помолотый:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Молоть - от древнего мелти. Но Е перешло в О перед твёрдым Л и
>   последующего развития полногласия. (Словарь Шанского)

См. [этимология слова "молоть"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C).

Но что интересно - народ активно употребляет слово "помеленный" вне всякой связи с мелом, оно живёт в языке!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Но что интересно - народ активно употребляет слово "помеленный" вне всякой связи с мелом, оно живёт в языке!* - ничего удивительного. Если бы Вы удосужились разобраться с ударениями, то поняли, что это другое слово. Просторечный вариант причастия именно от молоть, а не мелить.

Answer (score 0):

Слова *помолеть* нет, поисковик не дает вообще никакой информации об этом. А вот глагола *помелеть* находится, значение его можно узнать [здесь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/957166). Я вообще не вижу здесь никакой связи с кофе, однако второе слово, которое вы привели в вопросе, должно быть корректно.

Comment: Всё-таки, по-моему, Серж прав: второе слово корректно только как связанное с мелом, а не с кофе, а к кофе применимо **только** помолотый (если с приставкой *по*, молотый также).

Comment: *Всё-таки, по-моему, Серж прав:* - даже если и прав, это имеет мало отношения к вопросу.

Comment: *однако второе слово, которое вы привели в вопросе, должно быть корректно.* - оно безусловно корректно при двух условиях (на выбор): a) там понимается ё и оно связано напрямую с *мелом*. б) ударение на второе "е" и связано с "мелкий", "не глубокий". Вы уверены, что именно о такой "корректности" идет речь?

Answer (score 0):

Корректно: Помолотый кофе (от глагола помолоть)помелённый ( от глагола помелить -- натереть, помазать мелом).

Comment: Речь-то не о меле, а о молотом кофе.

Comment: Внимательно прочитайте мой ответ.

Comment: То есть Вы хотите сказать, что ни одного из вариантов автора вопроса не существует? Естественно, применительно к кофе, очевидно, что она о кофе только спрашивала.

Comment: Я хочу сказать,о молотом кофе правильно говорить: помолотый, а помеленный имеет значение: помазанный мелом.

Answer (score 0):

Кофе - мелют, глагол - молоть, помолоть. Причастия - молотый, помолотый.

============

Все остальное - это уже из другой оперы.

От помелеть (стать мелким) причастия страдательного быть не может, только помелевший. Но само слово довольно сомнительно, есть обмелеть - обмелевший. Или просто мелевший (несовершенный вид).

От мелить (покрывать мелом), помелить - помелёный, но слово тоже не из употребительных. Или просто мелённый (в варианте отглагольного прилагательного - с одним н - мелёный), это более свободно.

Ну а молен(н)ый (от молить) - это даже при большом желании трудно спутать, глагол "помолить" настолько редкий...

Вообще, думается, несколько несерьезно вспоминать все глаголы имеющие некоторое фонетическое сходство. Только путать вопрошающего.